# Is there a left()-function for Java strings?

Tags: java, string

I have an string str of unknown length (but not null) and a given maximum length len, this has to fit in. All I want to do, is to cut the string at len.

I know that I can use

```
str.substring(0, Math.min(len, str.length()));
```

but this does not come handy, if I try to write stacked code like this

```
code = str.replace(" ", "").left(len)
```

I know that I can write my own function but I would prefer an existing solution. Is there an existing left()-function in Java?

Comment: No, there isn't - what you have is in the Java `String` class.  There may be external libraries with additional methods - or you can write your own.

Comment: There's nothing built in, but Apache commons has the StringUtils class which has a suitable [left](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#left%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) function for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's nothing built in, but Apache commons has the StringUtils class which has a suitable [left](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#left%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) function for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to add the StringUtils Library you can still use it the way you want like so:

```
String string = (string.lastIndexOf(",") > -1 )?string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf(",")): string;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Split.

```
String str = "Result string Delimiter Right String";
System.out.println(str.split("Delimiter")[0].trim());
```

Output: "Result string"

Answer (score 1):

No there is not `left()` in the `String` class, as you can refer API. But as @Mark said Apache `StringUtils` has several methods: `leftPad()`, `rightPad()`, `center()` and `repeat()`. You can also check
 this:http://www.jdocs.com/lang/2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use String [Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

In this example the format specifier `"%-9s"` means minimum 9 characters  left justified (-).
`"%-9.9s"` means maximum 9 characters.

```
System.out.println (String.format("%-9.9s","1234"));
System.out.println (String.format("%-9.9s","123456789ABCD"));
int len=9;
System.out.println (String.format("%-"+len+"."+len+"s","123456789ABCD"));
```

Prints:

> ```
> 1234     
> 123456789
> 123456789
> ```

in OP's case it would be something like this:

```
static final int MAXLEN=9;
code = String.format("%-"+MAXLEN+"."+MAXLEN+"s",str.replace(" ", ""));
```

Answer (score -1):

put the below function in a class:

```
 public static String getLeftString(String st,int length){
    int stringlength=st.length();

    if(stringlength<=length){
        return st;
    }

    return st.substring((stringlength-length));
}
```

Comment: This gets the end of the string, so it's more similar to right();

Answer (score -1):

in my case I want to get date only.

`String s = "date:2021-01-01";`

`int n = s.length() - 10;`  //10 was the length of the date

`String result = s.substring(n);`

the result will be "2021-01-01";

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The question asks if there is an **existing** method to do this.  It does not ask how to do it.  And besides, your code is actually implementing something different from what the OP specified.  Read his code carefully.